# Selenium core, htmlsuite not generate for firefox

Tags: selenium

result.html is generated for * chrome and * safariProxy. For firefox is created empty. What is the problem?

Run:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -singleWindow -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.site.cz" "/Volumes/HTDOCS/temp/side/site.html" "/Volumes/HTDOCS/temp/side/results.html" -p 51013
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you be please more clear and explain the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes in the browser name